# Selecting only specific number in regex

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have a string

> can there be 10\ numbers and 100 numbers in this sentence

I want to select only 10 from this and replace it with a token "number" using `re.sub`

if use the regex `10[^\d+]` 
then the full match returns "10\" 
but I want only 10 to be selected without any leading or trailing characters or spaces.
How can I do this ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/F0MegD/1

Comment: Why not just "\d+" or "10\d*" or something like that?

Comment: I don't want all numbers I want only a specific number so "\d+" cannot help here